# Apply height of fixed parent to child element

Tags: css

I have a container inside a parent with fixed position, and want to apply the same height of the parent element to that container. But the height: 100% is not applying. What am I missing here?

```
.fixed-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  top: 50px;
  max-height: calc(100% - 100px);
}

.list-container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

https://codepen.io/NoahWetjen/pen/dyjVbRX

Comment: i think your max-height is the problem. change it to something like 400px.is that what you are looking for,and remove some of the list items? like this : https://jsfiddle.net/faLo7w02/

Comment: @ArashSeifi Unfortunately that specific max-height is required, but even with a 400px max-height, it does not work.

Comment: You are missing a [MCVE] in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Just add `display:flex; flex-direction:column` to `.fixed-container`

```css
.fixed-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  top: 50px;
  max-height: calc(100% - 100px);
  background: lightgreen;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.list-container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-container">
  <div class="list-container">
        <ul>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change `max-height` to `height` so both elements have the same height

Answer (score -1):

To be honest i dont really understand what you want. is this what you are looking for?

```css
.fixed-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  top: 50px;
  max-height: calc(100% - 100px);
  background: lightgreen;
  overflow:hidden
}

.list-container {
  height: inherit;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-container">
  <div class="list-container">
        <ul>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```